# How to initialize huge float arrays in java, android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, opengl-es

I was creating a opengl android application. I was trying to render a opengl object with vertices more than 50,000.

```
float itemVerts [] = {
// f 231/242/231 132/142/132 131/141/131
0.172233487787643f, -0.0717437751698985f, 0.228589675538813f,
0.176742968653347f, -0.0680393472738536f, 0.2284149434494f,
0.167979223684599f, -0.0670168837233226f, 0.24286384937854f,
// f 131/141/131 230/240/230 231/242/231
0.167979223684599f, -0.0670168837233226f, 0.24286384937854f,
0.166391290343292f, -0.0686544011752973f, 0.241920432968569f,......
```

and many more.... But when i do this in a function or constructor i get a error while compiling that The code of method () is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit. So I was wondering if there is a different way to do this.

I tried storing the value in file and reading it back. But the IO operation, with string parsing of such huge record is very slow. Takes more than 60 sec. Which is not good.

Please let me know if there is any other way to do this. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What about just itemVerts[0] = 0.172233487787643f; etc? Or, if you don't want to do that, do it in a scratch program and then serialize it to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i do this in a function or constructor i get a error while
>   compiling that The code of method () is exceeding the 65535 bytes
>   limit. So I was wondering if there is a different way to do this.

Put it outside the constructor (as a class variable or field)? If this doesn't change, just make it a constant. If it does change, make it a constant anyway and copy it in the constructor.

> I tried storing the value in file and reading it back. But the IO
>   operation, with string parsing of such huge record is very slow. Takes
>   more than 60 sec. Which is not good.

If you do decide to keep it in an external file and read it in, don't read it as a string, just serialize it somehow (Java serialization, Protocol Buffers, etc.).

Comment: changing it to constant or moving it to a function other than constructor is not working. Will try to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

The program don't have to parse the float if we *preprocess* the data.

Write another program that write all float to a binary file using `DataOutputStream`.

In your program, read them back using `DataInputStream`. You might want to chain it with `BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

For this cases I normally use the assets folder to store files in binary format (even you can define some kind of file format to include the vertex, normals etc...) and allocate it on application initialization as wannik explains.

Answer (score 0):

I would proprocess and store floats in binary form,   then mmap it as byte buffer and create fload array out of it.  This way you get float array, without parsing or allocation of space.